# Find Identity columns from another database

Tags: sql-server, identity, sql-server-2008-r2, information-schema

Normally with SQL Server you can use the `COLUMNPROPERTY` function like this to find the Identity columns in a database:

```
select TABLE_NAME + '.' + COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
and COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 1 
order by TABLE_NAME
```

But I can't figure out how to get this to work when running the query from another database. E.g. this does not return any results:

```
Use FirstDatabase
Go

select TABLE_NAME + '.' + COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME 
from SecondDatabase.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
and COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 1 
order by TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Object_ID only works in current db, unless you use a 3-part name, but that form is complicated to use.  Also, ColumnProperty only works in current db.

```
select o.name + '.' + c.name, o.name
from test1.sys.columns c
join test1.sys.objects o on c.object_id = o.object_id
join test1.sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = o.schema_id
where s.name = 'dbo'
  and o.is_ms_shipped = 0 and o.type = 'U'
  and c.is_identity = 1
order by o.name
```

Comment: Right - Object_id seems to work accross databases but ColumnProperty appears not to.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to get information with the help of COLUMNPROPERTY from another database. But there is on workaround:

```
DECLARE @DatabaseName VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @DatabaseName = 'MyDatabase'
SET @TableName = 'MyTable'

SET @SQL = '
SELECT 
    C.TABLE_NAME,
    C.COLUMN_NAME,
    S.IS_IDENTITY
FROM ' + @DatabaseName + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C
LEFT JOIN ' + @DatabaseName + '.SYS.COLUMNS AS S ON OBJECT_ID(''' + @DatabaseName + '.dbo.' + @TableName + ''') = S.OBJECT_ID AND C.COLUMN_NAME = S.NAME
WHERE S.IS_IDENTITY = 1'

EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: how is your answer different than the accepted one? even you said it is not possible?

Comment: Yes, it is not possible directly. But this code contains workaround that doing perfectly what topicstarter asked for: get identity information from the table in another DB.

Comment: My +1 is because the way INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS and SYS.COLUMNS are joined to get the result. Whereas the accepted answer does not use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS. In my case I had to use this.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me using a specific database:

```
USE <database_name>;
GO
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name
    , t.name AS table_name
    , c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
JOIN sys.identity_columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example, I've constructed a stored procedure in "Database1" that uses dynamic SQL to retrieve column information from a table in "Database2" (using the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] system view residing in "Database2"):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Database1].[Schema1].[ColumnNames] @Database2 nvarchar(128), @Schema2 nvarchar(128), @Table2 nvarchar(128)
AS

BEGIN
    DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(1000)

    SET @Sql = 'SELECT [COLUMN_NAME], [ORDINAL_POSITION] FROM [' + @Database2 + '].[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS]
                WHERE [TABLE_SCHEMA] = ''' + @Schema2 + ''' AND [TABLE_NAME] = ''' + @Table2 + ''''
    EXEC(@Sql)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using SQL Server 2019, and I have run into the same challenge.  I'm not sure if this fix will work for older versions, but there is a view in each DB called **Your-DB-Name.sys.identity_columns**.  If you select from this view, you'll see the list of identity columns you have defined in that DB.

From that information you should be able to write a join connecting **YourDBName.Information_schema.columns** such as below:

SELECT * 
FROM YourDBName.Information_Schema.columns col 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN YourDBName.sys.identity_columns idc
            ON idc.name = col.COLUMN_NAME AND idc.object_id = object_id('YourDBName..YourTableName')
WHERE col.TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableName' AND col.table_catalog = 'YourDBName';

The **YourDbName.sys.identity_columns** view contains the following fields that might be useful:

- **object_id** (used to join back to the table in question in case you have multiple tables with the same identity field name)
- **name** (the name of the Identity field)
- **column_id** (the order of the column in your table)
- **is_identity** (tells you if this is an identity field)
- **seed_value** (the initial value of the identity field)
- **increment_value** (how much the identity field goes up with each insert)